# Keep getting error when using file.exists

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Recently just started learning Ruby and have hit a wall. I am trying to use File.exists? but it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is my code.

```
puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist? to_file}"
puts "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
STDIN.gets
```

I keep getting an error saying: in 'exists?: cant convert nil into string (TypeError)

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`File::exist?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) methods expects a *string* value as its argument. But in your case argument `to_file` is `nil` for any reason. Now you used `".."`, so there *interpolation* is happening, so method call will be happened and will throw error if such `nil` is supplied as argument to the method `exist?`.

Write as below :

```
puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist?(to_file.to_s)}"
```

It will not throw error, as you are converting `nil` to empty string `""` now, or if any string value is there, same *string* will be returned. See the method [`NilClass#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) .